# video is not being written to file

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv to capture a video directly from webcam and saving it to a avi file. I have used the following code:

```
 #include "StdAfx.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int _tmain()
{
    VideoCapture src;
    src.open(1);
    if(!src.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"could not open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"camera opened\n";
    }

    int ex=static_cast<int>(src.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC));
    Size s(Size((int)src.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int)src.get((CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))));
    VideoWriter out;
    out.open("out.avi",ex,20,s);
    while(1)
    {
        Mat im;
        src>>im;
        imshow("vid",im);
        out<<im;
        char c;
        c=cvWaitKey(50);
        if(c==27)
            break;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

all the headers are included in stdafx.h.
But actually I am getting a avi file of size 0bite. How to fix this thing? I need to record the webcam video without displaying.

---

Note: I'm new in openCV and I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Hi, see the answer here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054907/opencv-videowriter-wont-write-anything-although-cvwritetoavi-does/12059944#12059944.. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no logical error in your program. The only problem is the `FOUR_CC` Codec you are using to write the video.

When I ran your code, I faced the exact problem as yours. When I added the error checking to the `out.open()` function, I found the problem.

Most probably, the FOUR_CC codec of the camera is not supported by the avi container.

As you are using Windows, a good option is to use `CV_FOURCC_PROMPT` in the 2nd argument of `out.open`.

This will open a pop up list box containing different FOUR_CC codecs available. If you don't know which one to choose, just select `Full Frames (Uncompressed)`. It is the most compatible option but will increase the size of the output video file.

The final code should look like this:

```
if(!out.open("out.avi",CV_FOURCC_PROMPT,20,s))
{
    cout<<"Writer Not Opened"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue, `CV_FOURCC_PROMPT ` did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

to run the application without display the webcam just delete

```
imshow("vid",im);
```

and **out.avi** size is 0 because you open it when the application is running (when you open the video stream and write on it ) , to open the video which you recorded , just close the application to end the write on the video and then open it .

Comment: I know that I should not write imshow(). But even after closing normally the file size is 0kbit